# Vedic age of earth

Tags: vishnu-purana, earth

I have read the time concept of Hinduism in Vishnu Purana, assembling all that data I have calculated the current age of earth, the calculations are as follow: 
Currently we have passed 6 manavantaras that is equal to 6 x 71 x 12000 = **1840320000** human years.
Also we are in kaliyuga of 27th mahayuga of 7th manavantra and 426881 human years are remaining in completetion of this current kali yuga, this means we have passed **3893119** human years of this manavantra.
Adding the years of current time which has passed i.e 1840320000 + 3893119 must give us the current age of earth which is equal to **1844213119** human years, approx equal to **1.84B**.

Now i have read many blogs which are claiming the vedic age of earth is equal to 4.32B which is far apart from my calculations. Also according to science the age of earth is found to be 4.32B years. But if you do the correct calculations you will get the same result as i am getting according to vishnu purana.

My question is who is wrong ? Me or the vedic blogs.

You can google vedic age of earth to find some relevant blogs

Please correct me if i am wrong.
Also if i am correct then why there is a huge difference of age in vedas and science.

Source:
http://www.bhakti-yoga-meditation.com/hinduism-age-of-the-earth.html

Comment: "You can google vedic age of earth to find some relevant blogs" - No, you should google and provide the relevant links here. The question has to be complete in all respects before anyone can start answering. You can find the Vishnu Purana here: http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/vp/index.htm

Comment: Here is one of them http://www.bhakti-yoga-meditation.com/hinduism-age-of-the-earth.html

Comment: You should edit and add everything to the question itself. You can use blockquotes.

Comment: Your calculation  is correct. One possibility is, time of Pralaya is not added. During Pralaya, only three worlds are destroyed. Also, whole process is described in Puranas in terms of Pancha bhutas (they don't mean gross fire, water, etc). So, correlating them with what Science knows  may give proper results.

Comment: I think vedic blogs said the total age of earth, which means 1 kalpa(Bramha day). Not the current age of earth.

Answer (score 3):

The Bhagavata Purana also gives the same timescale as the Vishnu Purana. Michael Cremo of ISKCON has calculated according to the Bhagavatam and got the result of approximately 2 billion years old.

You can read about it [here](http://www.forbiddenarcheology.com/).

As to why the age difference is about half the estimate of modern science, this could be for any reason.

Simply put, science is always changing, and when new observations come, new theories come and old ones go.

Comment: Or science is correct and hinduism got it wrong.